You do not have permission to call FormApp.openById
I have a form which I am using in app script by the FORMAPP.getbyurl/id method but every time I run this code I encounter an error

Error occurred: You do not have permission to call FormApp.openById. Required permissions: https://www.googleapis.com/auth/forms

the code works like this :- first it checks where in the edit is made then if the checkbox is ticked or not and lastly it autofill the form and submits it  can you guys help me please here is the code
function onEdit(e) {
  try {
    var range = e.range;
    var sheet = range.getSheet(); 
    var editedColumn = range.getColumn();
    var editedRow = range.getRow(); 
    
    if (sheet.getName() == "Sheet1" && editedColumn == 16) {
      var cell = range; 

      var isChecked = cell.getValue();

      if (isChecked === true) {
        var indentNumber = sheet.getRange(editedRow, 12).getValue();
        var formUrl = " https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSfs8jmdWuGGyvSsqU_HAG9pfaD_pSAwWc5YGHkI5wojiH6tjw/viewform";
        
        var form = FormApp.openById("1WlxVWcJ1llXS4pSFtfwzrxEzJVdIicDFXxIROcvPV5U");
        
        var rowData = sheet.getRange(editedRow, 1, 1, 14).getValues()[0];
        
        var formItems = form.getItems();
        formItems[0].asTextItem().createResponse(rowData[0]); 
        formItems[1].asTextItem().createResponse(rowData[1]); 
        
        var formResponse = form.submit();
        
        SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert('Form filled and submitted successfully.');
        
        cell.setValue(false);
      }
    }
  } catch (error) {
    Logger.log("Error: " + error.toString()); // Log error to Apps Script Execution log
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert('Error occurred: ' + error.message); // Display error message to user
  }
}

i was trying to get the form autofilled and autosubmitted

It just needs to be an installable trigger.   You can create it manually or programmaticallly and name it something other that onEdit.

The authorization error is because you are using a reserved function.
onEdit function can't access services which require authorization.
FormApp.openById() required authorization.
Change your function name and install the trigger manually.
You can read more about this here: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers
